# What does 転勤になる mean?

Tags: expressions

Is it an abbreviation of 転勤することになる？　How is it different from just 転勤する？

Example: 父は京都支店へ転勤になりました

Is it similar to the humbleness of 結婚になりました！？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you already know the [basics of how ことになる works](https://apieceofsushi.com/jlpt-n4-grammar-koto-ni-naru-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3-%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95-meaning/).

転勤することになりました normally refers to a future event (relative to the time of the statement). "It was decided that (someone) **would** be transferred."

転勤になりました can also refer to a future event, in which case the two sentences are interchangeable. But 転勤になりました can be used also to refer to a past event, like "(Someone) was transferred (following someone's decision)". So 先月転勤になりました usually means this person was actually transferred last month, whereas 先月転勤することになりました usually means such a decision was made last month (but the actual transfer may happen much later).

Note that `noun + になる` works like this only when the noun is inherently related to some decision/judgement (有罪, 合格, 採用, 離婚, etc.). Otherwise, `noun + になる` may mean something different. For example, 勉強することになりました means "(It was decided that) I am going to study", whereas 勉強になりました normally means "I learnd a lot / It was a good lesson".

Answer (score -1):

In this case, することになる adds a "ended up/resulted in" to  the sentence

It emphasizes on the result of getting a job transfer and makes it a decisive fact

The meaning for 転勤になる and 転勤する is almost the same imo, only difference is that 転勤する is the verb form